# nodeJS / Express: what's wrong with this RSVP promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, rsvp.js

I'm using nodeJS, running express4 framework to create an API. I am using RSVP.js for promises.

worker.getFamilies is called by an external module, not reflected here. The caller expects back an object with results.

Inside worker.getFamilies:
- I am querying mongoDB using mongoose (works, we get results back)

- I am using a promise to get the response object from mongoose when its available. That works.
- Then I try to return JSON.stringify(results); to the caller of worker.getFamilies and that doesnt work. The caller gets back "undefined". please help.

  ```
  var worker = exports;
  var RSVP = require('rsvp');

  var getFamiliesFromDB = function(DBconnection){
      var promise = new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
          DBconnection.find({} ,{limit:10, sort: [['_id',-1]]}).toArray(function(e, results){ 
              console.log('results:', results);
              resolve(results);
          });   
      });
      return promise;
  }

  worker.getFamilies = function(DBConnection){
      getFamiliesFromDB(DBConnection).then(function(results){

          //this works
          console.log('here are the fams from the promise', results);

          //this doesnt work like i want it to
          return JSON.stringify(results);
      });  
  };
  ```

Comment: Can the caller of `worker.getFamilies` accept a promise? If not, you have to force the request to be synchronous.

Comment: really? it seems to me the promise is finished by the time we get to return JSON.stringify(results); arent we just returning a 'normal' object by this point?

Comment: @quelquecosa [The result of an asynchronous task can't really be `return`ed.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) Such tasks are event-oriented and the `return` will either act before the event has occurred or, in this case, apply to the callback `function(results)` rather than `worker.getFamilies()`.

Comment: Just return inside of `worker.getFamilies`: `return getFamiliesFromDb(...)...`

Answer (score 2):

Well, for starters your `worker.getFamilies` function doesn't have a single `return` statement in it so that's why it returns `undefined` (this is what JavaScript returns automatically if you don't explicitly return).

Your only return there is inside the `.then` handler. You need to return the promise:

```
worker.getFamilies = function(DBConnection){
    // note how we've added a `return` here!
    return getFamiliesFromDB(DBConnection).then(function(results){
        console.log('here are the fams from the promise', results);
        return JSON.stringify(results);
    });  
};
```

Now that our function returns, we can use its return value:

```
// from caller site:
worker.getFamilies(dbconn).then(function(jsonResults){
    console.log("Got results!", jsonResults);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jonathan Lonowski explained, ["The result of an asynchronous task can't really be `return`ed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call).

There are a couple of solutions for this.

If you have control of the code calling `worker.getFamilies`. You can modify the code to:

```
worker.getFamilies = function(DBConnection){
    return getFamiliesFromDB(DBConnection).then(function(results) {
        return JSON.stringify(results);
    });  
};
```

The make the calling code do this:

```
worker.getFamilies(DBConnection).then(function(results) {
  console.log('now I can work with', results);
});
```

---

If you don't have control over the calling code, it becomes slightly more complicated:

```
var data;
worker.getFamilies = function() {
    return data;
};
getFamiliesFromDB(DBConnection).then(function(results) {
        data = JSON.stringify(results);
        // Here, start up the code where `worker.getFamilies` is used.
});
```

Basically, you need to make sure the result is ready before calling the code that needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are returning from a different context. Refactor `getFamilies` as follows:

```
worker.getFamilies = function(DBConnection, callback){
    getFamiliesFromDB(DBConnection).then(function(results){
        callback(JSON.stringify(results));
    });  
};
```

Since there at least one asynchronous function in the call-stack (in your case - `getFamiliesFromDb`) you need callbacks (or promises).

In your version, your `return` statement resolves to the callback function, not `getFamilies` as you would like to.

Another approach is to transform `getFamiliesFromDB` to a synchronous call. Either using mongoose API or waiting for the promise to resolve and return it's resolved data.

Comment: Since OP is already using promises, he should not degrade them to callbacks again.